# How do I distinguish folders with the same name in Unity?

Tags: unity, 14.04

In Unity, the meta key brings up a quick search bar. Handy. But if I have multiple directories or files with the same name (say ... README) there doesn't appear to be any way to distinguish them: 
 [image: Don't ask why I have so many directories named "engagement"]

Hovering over the folder icon doesn't expose anything. Selecting one icon exposes the directory (or file) size and modification date. I can open, reveal or email it, but I still don't know which directory the file is in.

Is there any way to expose that information?

Comment: We should file a bug to add a feature. I think adding file/folder address to Dash will be ok.

Comment: Ideally when I hover over the icon the full path would be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this problem is more a design flaw, than an actual error. This is the intended behaviour, even if it is confusing.

My recommendation would be to explain your problem to the developing team, and either let them come up with a solution (or you can suggest one if you have a good idea) and hope that they might implement it at any point.